# FindInstance with assumptions

Tags: equation-solving

Let

$$\frac{5 e^4 (3-4 c \epsilon )}{c^2+1}=20$$
$$\frac{4 e^5 (2 c+11 \epsilon )}{c^2+1}=-32$$

How can I find $e,\,c,\,\epsilon$ such that

$$\qquad\epsilon = \pm 1,\,c>0,\,e\neq 0\, {\rm and}\, e,\,c\in \mathbb{Q}$$

I tried:

```
With[{ϵ = ±1, c > 0, e != 0, {e, c, ϵ} ∈ Rationals}, 
  FindInstance[
    {20 == (5 e^4 (3 - 4 c ϵ))/(1 + c^2), 
     32 == -((4 e^5 (2 c + 11 ϵ))/(1 + c^2))}, 
    {c, e, ϵ}]]
```

but I got no answer.

Comment: `FindInstance[{20 == (5 e^4 (3 - 4 c \[Epsilon]))/(1 + c^2), 
  32 == -((4 e^5 (2 c + 11 \[Epsilon]))/(1 + c^2)), \[Epsilon] == 
    1 || \[Epsilon] == -1, c > 0, {e, c} \[Element] Rationals}, {c, 
  e, \[Epsilon]}]`

Comment: Or you can use @corey979 answer and replace `FindInstance` with either  `Solve` or `Reduce` to see that the result provided by `FindInstance` is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FindInstance[{20 == (5 e^4 (3 - 4 c ϵ))/(1 + c^2), 
  32 == -((4 e^5 (2 c + 11 ϵ))/(1 + c^2)),
    ϵ == 1 || ϵ == -1, c > 0, e != 0, {e, c} ∈ Rationals},
 {c, e, ϵ}]
```

and

```
Solve[{20 == (5 e^4 (3 - 4 c ϵ))/(1 + c^2), 
  32 == -((4 e^5 (2 c + 11 ϵ))/(1 + c^2)),
    ϵ == 1 || ϵ == -1, c > 0, e != 0, {e, c} ∈ Rationals},
 {c, e, ϵ}]
```

give

> {{c -> 1/2, e -> 1, ϵ -> -1}}

consistent with

```
Reduce[{20 == (5 e^4 (3 - 4 c ϵ))/(1 + c^2), 
  32 == -((4 e^5 (2 c + 11 ϵ))/(1 + c^2)),
    ϵ == 1 || ϵ == -1, c > 0, e != 0, {e, c} ∈ Rationals},
 {c, e, ϵ}]
```

> c == 1/2 && e == 1 && ϵ == -1